# C Standard - Comma Operator Syntax

Tags: c, comma-operator

according to the C Standard (and K&R) the syntax of the Comma-Operator is as follows:

```
expression:
    assignment-expression
    expression, assignment-expression
```

But why does this statement work?

```
5+5, 1+1;
```

5+5 and 1+1 are not assignment-expressions, but the C Standard requires assignment-expressions as operands for the Comma-Operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`assignment-expression` ⊃ `conditional-expression` ⊃ `logical-OR-expression` ⊃ `logical-AND-expression` ⊃ `inclusive-OR-expression` ⊃ `exclusive-OR-expression` ⊃ `AND-expression` ⊃ `equality-expression` ⊃ `relational-expression` ⊃ `shift-expression` ⊃ `additive-expression` which finally are ⊃ `additive-expression + multiplicative-expression`.

So no, 5+5 is indeed ∈ `assignment-expression`.

---

⊃ is the "contains" relation.

Comment: In other words, the symbols in the language's formal grammar have to be interpreted as defined in the grammar.  Any English-language-based interpretation implied by their spelling is at best a guideline.

Answer (score 2):

The way the C grammar is defined may not be obvious in the first place.

First, let's look how the `assignment-expression` is defined:

```
(6.5.16) assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

This means that it can be *either* `conditional-expression` or the latter combination of tokens. The former is defined as:

```
(6.5.15) conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

Eventually, you will encounter:

```
(6.5.7) shift-expression:
    additive-expression
    shift-expression << additive-expression
    shift-expression >> additive-expression
```

where `additive-expression` corresponds to expressions such `1+1`.